Apply tagQuery to text converted to html using the HTML functions from htmltools
I want to modify some HTML using the tagQuery function from the htmltools package, but I stumbled on the following situation:
# From https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/reference/HTML.html

el <- div(HTML("I like <u>turtles</u>"))

# Then say I want to modify it

tagQuery(el)$child()

This results in the following error:
Error:
! `setSelected(selected=)` received a list item at position `1` that was not a tag environment
Show Traceback

It's like it is not recognising the nested structure of html. (This gives me an empty selection too: tagQuery(el)$find("*"))
I have this character also that when formatted as html using HTML and then giving it to tagQuery() gives me an error:
tagQuery(
  '<tr>
  <td headers="first" class="gt_row gt_left">Joe</td>
  <td headers="last" class="gt_row gt_left">Blow</td>
  <td headers="phone" class="gt_row gt_right">123-456-7890</td>
  <td headers="email" class="gt_row gt_left">joe3@example.com</td>
  <td headers="col_editar" class="gt_row gt_center"><div class="gt_from_md">
  <p><a href="/contacts/5/edit">Edit</a></p>
  </div></td>
  <td headers="col_ver" class="gt_row gt_center"><div class="gt_from_md">
  <p><a href="/contacts/5">View</a></p>
  </div></td>
  </tr>' |> 
    HTML()
)

Error:
Error in `tagQuery()`:
! The initial set of tags supplied to `tagQuery()` must have at least 1 standard tag object. Ex: `div()`


I don't think that this is possible. From section 2.4 of Outstanding User Interfaces with Shiny:  Doing so [i.e. using HTML()], you will not be able to use tag-related functions, as in the next parts. The reason is that HTML() will create a raw HTML string not a tag list required for tagQuery(), e.g. el <- div(p("I like ", tags$u("turtles"))); tagQuery(el)$children() will work. The book  also mentions a Shiny app to convert raw HTML to R code: https://alandipert.shinyapps.io/html2r/
